# npm install karma script launcher error

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

I don't know what the problem can be. I deleted my node_modules folder first and I'm trying to do an npm install from scratch.

I keep getting the following error when I try to do a clean npm install of node_modules. I sometimes get this error with karma-script-launcher and sometimes I get it with karma-chrome-launcher.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

```
karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 node_modules/karma-script-launcher
npm ERR! Error: Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!     at errorHandler (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:80:16)
npm ERR!     at save (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:329:12)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:98:7
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:188:5
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:119:5
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:233:14
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
```

My package.json has:

"karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
"karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
"karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
"karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "~0.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~0.1.0",

Answer (score 0):

Updating npm might solve the issue:

```
npm install npm -g
```